# how do i create new objects through activerecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a table Switches and Snapshots. A Switch has many Snapshots, a Snapshot belongs to one Switch. Iam not able to create a new Snapshot through the association. Below my code.

```
2.6.3 :014 > switch = Switch.new
 => #<Switch id: nil, switch: nil, ip_address: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.6.3 :015 > switch.create_snapshot
NoMethodError (undefined method `create_snapshot' for #<Switch:0x00000000039950e0>)
```

app/model

```
class Switch < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :snapshots

end

class Snapshot < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :switch

end
```

psql configured via migrations

```
\d switches
Indexes:
    "switches_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "snapshots" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_5537742698" FOREIGN KEY (switch_id) REFERENCES switches(id)

# \d snapshots
Indexes:
    "snapshots_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_snapshots_on_switch_id" btree (switch_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_5537742698" FOREIGN KEY (switch_id) REFERENCES switches(id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the switch, after that you are able to create snapshots like this

```
switch = Switch.new 
switch.save
or
switch = Switch.create(switch_params)
```

then

```
switch.snapshots.create(snapshot_params)
```

And if you want to create snapshots along with switch creation, then you should use nested attributes https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: that does actually work. thanks. In the past i used the mentioned syntax. Did this change or why was I able in the past to use switch.create_snapshot ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :model` on the the parent model.

Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent. By default nested attribute updating is turned off and you can enable it using the #accepts_nested_attributes_for class method. When you enable nested attributes an attribute writer is defined on the model. (from [api.rubyonrails.org](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html))

Answer (score 0):

To create the associated object together, there can be an alternative way like this-

```
switch = Switch.new(swich_params)
switch.snapshots.build
switch.save
```

After creating a `switch` it will create associated `snapshots` also.